# Download documents with SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

Isn't `SFSafariViewController` able to download documents? I'm trying to do this, but the "Save to" dialog doesn't appear. From the same page opened in native Safari it opens.

My implementation is basic:

```
 let svc = SFSafariViewController(URL: NSURL(string: self.urlString)!)
 present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to download file using SFSafariViewController.

Comment: Welcome ! @Alex bartis