# Download Zip file through SFSafariViewController or Webview in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am loading `SFSafariViewController` in my Xamarin iOS and loading `https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_fotohound/downloads/sample-pictures/Sample/Sample-Pictures.zip/` this URL.

When I hit this URL in my Safari App, a Zip file is automatically downloaded and a `Open In..` option comes.

BUT nothing happens when i load this url in my App in `SFSafariViewController` or `Webview`

Comment: Is there a reason you are not to using HttpClient and streaming the response to file?

Comment: nothing in particular but if u could help me... a bit more in details pls. Because lets say i have a responsive URL that needs to be loaded in my SFSafariViewController. Now when the URL is loaded there is a button click in the Web page that downloads items. Will this at all work ?

Comment: Not possible to download with SFSafariViewController. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518443/download-documents-with-sfsafariviewcontroller